# Link a shared webhosting to an external domain

Tags: dns, shared-hosting, domain-name

I'm confusing on something!

If I map a domain with 1&1 with a shedhosting with bluehost. Do this means that I can manage my domain from bluehost ?

in other words can I manage my domain with 1a1 (emails, subdomains...) from my bluehost without transferring it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. By the default, your domain nameservers will use registrar nameservers, in your case 1&1 service. Simply login to your 1&1 account, then change your domain nameservers to bluehost nameservers. You can find your hosting nameservers in your hosting cPanel (I assume that bluehost use cPanel). Or, if you find a trouble finding the nameservers, simply contact bluehost customer service.

After change the nameservers, then check it first to make sure the changes was take effect, use http://who.is service. Then go to your bluehost cPanel, you can manage domain name directly from there, add/remove subdomain, change dns record (A Record, CNAME, etc..) and also your mail will functioned (I assume that bluehost give you an email hosting service in your hosting package).

NOTE: You don't need to transfer your domain to bluehost, you can have your domain registrar different from your hosting provider. The only thing you need to do just pointing nameservers to your hosting nameservers.
REMEMBER: All your domain record in 1&1 account will not functioned, you need to move it to your bluehost cPanel. All A Record, CNAME, etc in your 1&1 panel must be re-written in your bluehost cPanel.

I use this method right now, and everything is ok!

Comment: Thanks, but how they know I'm the owner of the domain ? all shared hosts have the same nameserver.